# MSI installation doesn't work for quiet installation

Tags: windows-installer

While trying to install one of my msi file through quiet installation, (Through msiexec /qn /i command)I get the following error.

**You do not have sufficient privileges to complete this installation for all users of the machine.  Log on as administrator and then retry this installation.**

But through normal /i it works. Why is this discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

MSI can't throw up a UAC confirmation when running silently.  The launching process has to already be elevated.